# What are the ways to show static content on new page in GWT application?

Tags: user-interface, gwt

I have a GWT application in which I want to show some static content in new tab.

```
private native void openResultWindow(String contents) /*-{
    var printWindow = window.open("", "PrintWin", "scrollbars=yes", false);
    printWindow.document.open("text/html","replace");
    if (printWindow && printWindow.top) {
        printWindow.document.write(contents);

    } else {
        alert("The print feature works by opening a popup window, but our popup window was blocked by your browser.  If you can disable the blocker temporarily, you'll be able to print here.  Sorry!");
    }
}-*/;
```

Right now I am using the above code to show the static content as simple html page styled with CSS. The ***contents*** variable passed to the function contains the HTML string. But I need richer UI. Are there any other UI options which can be integrated with GWT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render something really complex and want to integrate other UIs then what you should open the window with a URL instead of passing the content directly, the URL should point to a server where the static/dynamic content should be served, this could be any html page with what ever css and styles desired. or could be a servlet, or event another GWT application.

Comment: I have created a html page on the server side and provided the url in `var printWindow = window.open("", "PrintWin", "scrollbars=yes", false);` (first argument) instead of empty string. But it is opening a new tab with "about:blank" as url.